# The same song plays on 2 different browser tabs, how can I disable it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jplayer, audio-player

We're currently testing a music service on a private dev server built using rails.  We're using Jplayer for streaming, and everything works well except one issue.

**The bug:**

If a user opens a browser tab, plays a song, then opens another tab and plays any song, the song in the previous browser will start playing the same song that was just clicked in the new tab.

**The desired solution:**

We want to force only one instance of a browser playing a song at any given time.  So if a user opens a new instance of the site and starts playing a song, the song from the previous instance will automatically stop.

I'm assuming this is a Jplayer issue, but could it be something else?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a long shot and very theoretical but here it goes.

I don't think it's Jplayer issue but a missing feature in the Rails web app.

Possibly use a new controller or model which accepts one song at a time to be played? So when the user selects a music to be played, the web app would push the selected music into the new controller/model which Jplayer would be played from. The controller/model would only have the one particular song/track.

Or using `request.remote_ip` and a method to detect if there's two or more streams of music being streamed to the users computer and to pause the music on the other tabs when the most recent song is being played. Could help if you're also using a JavaScript framework like Backbone.js to implement this.